# Kendo delete button not working

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

Kendo is throwing error when trying to delete. It shows confirmation box after OK then it deletes the row, but doesn't call destroy in transport to call Api service.

```
kendo.all.min.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at init._removeRow (kendo.all.min.js:52)
at init.removeRow (kendo.all.min.js:52)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (kendo.all.min.js:51)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
_removeRow @ kendo.all.min.js:52
removeRow @ kendo.all.min.js:`enter code here`52
(anonymous) @ kendo.all.min.js:51
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: You really need to provide more information than just the error message. How is the transport set up? Is the api actually being called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, persistSelection was true. I deleted it. now its working !!